# ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis when making DataFrame from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary with a similar format as the dictionary below:

```
{'ID': Unnamed: 0
 2019-04-17 06:54:24    {'a': 6.75, 'b': 7.4}
 2019-04-17 07:04:24    {'a': 6.75, 'b': 7.4}
 2019-04-17 07:13:24    {'a': 6.75, 'b': 7.4}
 dtype: object, 'ID2': Unnamed: 0
 2019-04-17 06:54:44    {'a': 6.35, 'b': 7.0}
 2019-04-17 07:04:44    {'a': 6.35, 'b': 7.0}
 2019-04-17 07:13:24    {'a': 6.35, 'b': 7.0}
 dtype: object, 'ID3': Unnamed: 0
 2019-04-17 06:52:44    {'a': 6.65, 'b': 7.3}
 2019-04-17 07:02:04    {'a': 6.65, 'b': 7.3}
 2019-04-17 07:10:24    {'a': 6.65, 'b': 7.3}
 dtype: object, 'ID4': Unnamed: 0
 2019-04-17 06:54:44    {'a': 5.45, 'b': 5.95}
 2019-04-17 07:04:44    {'a': 5.45, 'b': 5.95}
 2019-04-17 07:13:24    {'a': 5.45, 'b': 5.95}
 dtype: object}
```

When I try to perform

```py
pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

I know this isn't very helpful but I could not reproduce this error. Note there are some series with the same index eg. between ID2 and ID4 above.

Answer (score 0):

Use dictionary comprehension with `DataFrame` constructor and `concat`:

```
df = pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v.squeeze().values.tolist(), index=v.index) 
               for k, v in d.items()})
print (df)

                            a     b
ID  2019-04-17 06:54:24  6.75  7.40
    2019-04-17 07:04:24  6.75  7.40
    2019-04-17 07:13:24  6.75  7.40
ID2 2019-04-17 06:54:44  6.35  7.00
    2019-04-17 07:04:44  6.35  7.00
    2019-04-17 07:13:24  6.35  7.00
ID3 2019-04-17 06:52:44  6.65  7.30
    2019-04-17 07:02:04  6.65  7.30
    2019-04-17 07:10:24  6.65  7.30
ID4 2019-04-17 06:54:44  5.45  5.95
    2019-04-17 07:04:44  5.45  5.95
    2019-04-17 07:13:24  5.45  5.95
```

If values are string repr of dictionaries:

```
import ast

df = pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame([ast.literal_eval(x) for x in v.squeeze()], index=v.index) 
                for k, v in d.items()})
```